# VBA WebScraping content from nested frames: access denied

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

This isn't an important task, but it is one that I thought would be easy and has instead been very frustrating. I'm trying to grab the current print counter values from our MFP but I am not able to get past the second Frame on the page.

In fact, it seems to continually loop me back to the top as I try to go "deeper" into the page.

The data I am after is stored in the "contents" frame.

HTML Source - Nested Frames

[image: HTML Source - Nested Frames]

```
Sub Copy_Count()
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim strURL() As String

Dim HTML_Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim HTML_Doc2 As HTMLDocument

' There will be additional machines to retrieve data from, current copier must navigate to main page first before counter.
strURL = Split("http://192.168.50.26/?MAIN=DEVICE,http://192.168.50.26/?MAIN=COUNTER&SUB=TOTAL", ",")

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Navigate2 strURL(0)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

IE.Navigate2 strURL(1)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


Set HTML_Doc = IE.Document

' This get's me to "TopLevelFrame"
Debug.Print HTML_Doc.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(0).getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).Document.Body.innerHTML

' Assign the document of the TopLevelFrame
Set HTML_Doc2 = HTML_Doc.getElementsByTagName("frameset")(0).getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).Document


    Debug.Print HTML_Doc2.getElementById("TotalFullColor")
    Debug.Print HTML_Doc.getElementById("TotalFullColor").innerText
    Debug.Print IE.Document.GetElementsByID("TotalFullColor")(1)

End Sub
```

Windows 10 Pro, IE 11, Office Pro Plus 2016